# TFS project structure for Java Project using Maven Release

Tags: java, maven

I am looking to host a Java project that will be managed using Maven Release in a TFS server.

Is there a TFS repository structure that should be followed for this?

Typically in SVN we'd have /trunk, /branch, /tags -- is this structure required for maven release to work fully? Is there a best way to structure it?

Answer (score 0):

The `trunk`, `branches` and `tags` namespaces are convention used by Subversion, and don't really impact Maven.  For TFS, I would recommend an approach based on the [TFS Branching and Merging Guidance](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases) produced by the ALM Rangers.

For instance, my team is the "TEE" team, and our main projects are at `$/TEE/main`.  We create branches in two locations - one location is for release branches, the other is for feature branches.  They are `$/TEE/Releases` and `$/TEE/Feature`, respectively.

This leads to a folder structure that looks like:

```
$/TEE/Feature/SecretUpcomingFeature
$/TEE/Feature/OtherUpcomingFeature
$/TEE/main
$/TEE/Releases/10
$/TEE/Releases/10SP1
```

etc.

Each of these folders, of course, contains a Maven superproject and the subprojects.

Comment: Edward - thanks for the info. Can you speak to how the Maven release plugin works with this? IIRC with svn, when you perform a release it will tag the project as X.X.X, etc.

Comment: Edward - also, is it fair to saw that your "team" (TEE) is equivalent to a project? All the maven projects under the TEE tree are all just variations of the same "main" project, correct?

Comment: @empire29 I'm afraid we don't use the maven release plugin, we do a label of every release we make, and we do so manually in Source Control Explorer in Eclipse.  (Labels are fairly conceptually similar to tags in svn.)

Comment: As for the organization question, yes, you're exactly right, each branch is a variation on `main`.